# How can I create a client spec from older revision of a template?

Tags: perforce, perforce-client-spec

I can create a perforce client spec from a template with:

```
% p4 client -t template_spec
```

Is it possible to tell `p4 client` to use a previous revision of the template client?

I wrongly assumed one of those commands would work:

```
% p4 client -t template_spec#4
% p4 client -t template_spec@2019/05/01
```

I get the error "Revision chars (@, #) not allowed in 'template_spec@2019/05/01'.

I also considered having `p4 client` to describe the content but this one does not work either:

```
% p4 client -o template_spec@2019/05/01
```

But I get same error as above.

I'm looking for a solution using the command line only, not involving p4v.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With streams (which are essentially the modern version of template clients) you can do this via the `StreamAtChange` field, which causes your client view to be based on the version of a stream as of a given changelist number.

With classic clients, you'll need to use a spec depot and do something like:

```
p4 print -q //spec/template_spec#4 | sed -e "s/template_spec/new_client/" | p4 client -i
```